# Cloud SQL Proxy -credential-file flag is not working. It always says not defined hence no file was found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I placed my service account key file into the same directory where I execute the cloud sql proxy client from. When starting with the following

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=game:europe-west4:world-alpha=tcp:3306 -credential-file=proxy_key.json
```

the CLI says:

```
flag provided but not defined: -credential-file
```

I don't understand what the problem is? What is the convention to point to the key file? I also tried `./proxy_key.json` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag is misspelled.

Use **-credential_file** instead of **-credential-file**.